# React redux: Cannot set on an immutable record

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am trying to update my redux model from my reducer. The model is an extension of an Immutable Record class. I am trying to update the Record with the set method:

```
import { List, Record } from 'immutable';
import { IFaqItem } from './api.models';

export interface IFaqsState {
  loading?: boolean;
  items?: List<IFaqItem>;
}
const faqsState = Record({
  loading: false,
  items: List()
});

class FaqsState extends faqsState implements IFaqsState {
  loading: boolean;
  items: List<IFaqItem>;

  with(props: IFaqsState) {
    this.set('loading', props.loading);
    return this;
  }
}

export default FaqsState;
```

The reducer contains the following:

```
case ActionTypes.FAQS_GET_AJAX_RECEIVE:
  let response: IFaqsGetResponse = action.payload.response && action.payload.response.response;
  return state.with({
    loading: false,
    items: List(response)
  });
```

However this gives me the following error:

```
Error: Cannot set on an immutable record.
```

**UPDATE**

When I change the reducer from:

```
let initial = new FaqsState();

const faqsReducer: Reducer<FaqsState> = (state = initial, action: AppActions) => {
```

to:

```
const faqsReducer: Reducer<FaqsState> = (state = null, action: AppActions) => {

  state = new FaqsState();
```

it seems to work. Why is it not working when I give the initial state in as an argument?

Comment: On what line do you get the exception? Is it actually on the following line?
this.set('loading', props.loading);

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is **immutable**. When you called the `with` function you mutated the object, thus violating it's only constraint.
To avoid that, you should create a new instance with the new values and return it to the store.

Comment: When I look at the docs: https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record, I see that Set is a method of Record and is supposed to work the way I have implemented it

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
with(props: IFaqsState) {
  return this.set('loading', props.loading);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this gives me the same error. which is strange since the set method is supposed to return a new instance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following approach to update your reducer
Define a state

```
let initialState = {
   // Create an immutable object 
   list: { loading: true, list: []}
};
```

Then in switch case,

```
case ActionTypes.FAQS_GET_AJAX_RECEIVE:
    let response: IFaqsGetResponse = action.payload.response && 
    action.payload.response.response;
    return {...initialState.list, loading: false, items:List(response)}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your update, whenever your reducer is called, a new `state = new FaqsState();` is created.

While in your previous implementation, `let initial = new FaqsState();` is one-time created and out-of-scope for the reducer function, and thus the same reference/record is recyclingly used for every subsequent calls of the reducer. When this reducer is first called, the `initial` is empty and can be called with `with` to set `initial`'s value, but after that, `initial`'s value is already set, and the second call on the reducer will attempt to "overwrite" the `initial`'s value, result in exception.

However, I would suggest you signature to this for brevity and correctness

```js
const faqsReducer: Reducer<FaqsState> = (state =(new FaqsState()), action: AppActions) => {
```

because your updated reducer cannot get previous state value.